# How to log DOM styles in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

How can one print out a particular style in the console?

This is my current (failed) attempt.

```
var test = document.getElementById("moop");
console.log(test.style.backgroundPostion);
```

Comment: What did that code actually do?

Comment: returned 'undefined' in the console

Comment: show your HTML as well

Comment: Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element? And does the element have a `style` attribute, or did you use a stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle):

```
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(test).backgroundPosition);
```